# how to print a float to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, precision, python-3.7, floating-accuracy

I want number from input to print out with 2 decimal places. You can assume that the number will always be a float.

```
num = 20.0
```

Desired output - `20.00`.

I've tried this code:

```
num = round(num, 2)
num = float('{0.2f}'.format(num))
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
print('{0.2f}'.format(num))
```

When you turn this string back into a float with `float()` the formatting is lost.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do to the float value, as long as it is still a float, it does not have any internal concept of decimal places.

If you want to *display* two decimal places, then that happens when you *convert to text* - which *everything* you `print` is, whether you asked for the conversion or not. You cannot make `num` "be" `20.00` as opposed to `20.0`, because those *aren't actually different things*. (And keep in mind that the float simply [cannot represent all decimal values exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).)

Therefore, we use string formatting *in the print call*:

```
num = 20.0
print('{.2f}'.format(num))
# Or, using f-strings:
print(f'{num:.2f}')
```